# How to remove a function called on document ready depending on window size?

Tags: jquery, events

I've tried Googling this as much as I could but I can't seem to find the answer. So if you could, please leave me with some advices.

I've just learnt to wrap my functions up like this (not sure what this technique is called sorry):

```
$(document).ready({
    myFunc.init();
});

var myFunc = {
    init: function() {
        // do a number of things
    }
};
```

What I need to do for responsive is to init the function when the window is bigger than a certain size, and remove the function when the window is less than a certain size.

In my mind it should be a simple way to do something like this:

```
$(document).ready({
    myFunc.init();
});
$(window).resize(function(){
    if($(window).width() > 700) {
        myFunc.init();
    } else {
        // remove myFunc.init()
    }
});
```

The closest thing I came across is unbind/die, is this what I'm suppose to use here? If so, how do I use it? Please help.

Comment: What does `remove myFunc.init()` mean?

Comment: hi @zerkms, because the myFunc seems to be carried over when the window resizes below 700, I need to remove it.

Comment: but the function only executes once on document load right? then why can't you just put the if before calling the function?

Comment: @koala_dev no it also executes when the window resizes

Comment: Your document ready function doesn't call a function, it's `$(document).ready(function() { ... });`

Comment: can you make a simple fiddle showing how your code is right now?

Comment: There is no such thing as "remove function call". You need to explain our task better

Comment: What does `init()` do, once it's called, you can't take it back again, you have to create another function that removes whatever you did in `init()`.

Comment: @koala_dev my function is quite long, but i'll make a fiddle with simpler codes now if thats ok?

Comment: @adeneo ok so there's no way to destroy a function once its called? I need to make another function to reset everything i've done in the init()?

Comment: @muudless that's ok as long as it shows how it is binding to the resize event

Comment: @zerkms i'm doing my best to explain, i'm still a beginner. but i appreciate you letting me know that there's no such thing. cheers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'd normally do this as :

```
var myFunc = {
    I_ran : false,
    init  : function() {
        // do a number of things
        if (! this.I_ran ) {

            this.elem = $('<div>');
            this.elem.appendTo('body');

            this.I_ran = true; // avoid multiple calls, 
                               // as resize fires continously
        }
    },
    destroy: function() {
        if (this.elem.length) this.elem.remove();
        this.I_ran = false;
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    $(window).on('resize', function() {

        if ($(this).width() > 700) {
            myFunc.init();
        }else{
            myFunc.destroy();
        }

    }).trigger('resize');
});
```

Comment: This looks like its exactly what I need. I will test it out and let you know! cheers!

Comment: It's a general example of how to create an object literal with an init and a destroy method. The init method will append an element, and you then have to manually remove that element in the destroy method. There is no magic way to get it back to how it was before init was called.

Comment: Thank you so much, this was exactly what I needed. You gave me the term 'object literal' in your comment which enabled me to find out other answers I would've otherwise not have known how to search for.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using wrong `syntax` of **document.ready** it should be like,

```
function test()
{
   if($(window).width() > 700) {
       myFunc.init();
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    test();
    $(window).resize(function(){
        test();           
    });
});
```

Also, there is no need to **unbind** the `function` if you unbind then `next time` how it will `initialize again`, so `if condition` is correct to use here.